# GAEでechoを動かそうとするとcan't find import: "context"と表示される

Tags: go, google-app-engine, go-echo

お世話になります。
現在、GAEの環境でechoを動かそうとしていますが「can't find import: "context"」と表示されて動かすことができておりません。

下記のように表示されます

```
golang.org/x/crypto/acme/acme.go:18: can't find import: "context"
```

goappとgoversionは下記になります

```
go version go1.8 darwin/amd64
go version 1.6.3 (appengine-1.9.53) darwin/amd64
```

どなたか、ご教授いただければ幸いです。
すいませんが、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/68670 とか参考になりますかね？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。こちら、確認をしてみましたが今回エラーの出ているパッケージとはちょっと事情が違うようで・・・直接的には使えそうにありませんでした。

Comment: 上記の件ですが、URL先と同様にGo1.7に対応したコミットが入っておりました。 該当のモジュールのリポジトリをチェックアウトすることで解決できました、ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

echo が context を使うため Go 1.7 に対応したコミットをしたものの、この時点での GAE で使える Go が 1.6 で[あった](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/release-notes#june_27_2017)ためエラーが出ています。古いコミットをチェックアウトすることで一時的に解決できます。

現在は GAE でも Go 1.7 が使えるため、GAE 側の Go のバージョンを上げることで対応できます。

<sub>-- [spitsonさん](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/15705/spitson)の[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/34606/gae%E3%82%92echo%E3%81%A7%E5%8B%95%E3%81%8B%E3%81%9D%E3%81%86%E3%81%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8#comment34373_34606)と[質問者さん](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/23063/go%E8%A8%80%E8%AA%9E%E5%AD%A6%E7%BF%92%E4%B8%AD)の[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/34606/gae%E3%82%92echo%E3%81%A7%E5%8B%95%E3%81%8B%E3%81%9D%E3%81%86%E3%81%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8#comment34378_34606)に、少し追記しました。</sub>